# Whats the best way to store booking information over multiple pages without DB in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'll try and cover most of the important details here...

I'm currently working on a booking system for a transport provider. I am using Laravel and originally started by having the Booking model attached to a User.

The client now however wants them to not have to login or register until the last step of the booking process. I have done carts etc in Session / Local Storage before but I thought before I start I would get some input from the friendly folks over at StackOverflow!

The most ideal way for me at this point would be to make the user_id on the Booking model nullable, but then when the visitor returns to the site how will I then know which booking is theirs?

I hope this makes sense & I hope someone out there has dealt with a similar problem to this one and can shed some light on the best strategy going forward!

Comment: Is there something wrong with the sessions approach?

Answer (score 1):

I created something similar to what you say in a company that has been working for some time, I indicate how I proposed it, to see if it can help you achieve what you want to achieve in the most optimal way.

As you indicated, I created the reservations with the nullable **user_id**, as it usually happens in almost all reserve applications, they are not eternal, so I added a field (**max_datetime**) of maximum time that reservation would last and a field (**token**) with code only for the reservation, in addition to a field (**ip**) for the ip of the session. (In the application that I made, the reservation was maintained 12 hours maximum or until 11:59 pm on the same day, which may be less than 12 hours).

Then create a [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) for a custom [Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan). What it did was eliminate the reserves that fulfilled the condition to be eliminated.

When the reservation was completed it was associated with the **user_id** and the other fields with null (**max_datetime**, **token**, **ip**). Ah! Yes and a field (**confirmed**) to confirm with "true" that the reservation has been completed, by default to "false".

I used session to check the "**ip**" and the "**token**", and if not, I asked that if they had the token, to indicate it.
The system allowed you to obtain the "**token**" in case you did not want to continue at that moment, warning you of the time the reservation was kept.

I do not have access to the code since it was from a company and I only kept the idea. I hope it helps you. A cordial greeting.